# Java class type mismatch in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to import the `Color` class from `javafx`, and use it in a scala class.
But when I use my class somewhere else, I get this error:

```
Error:(9, 50) type mismatch;
 found   : javafx.scene.paint.Color
 required: drawingengine.Color
```

Here is the code:

```
package drawingengine
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
sealed class Pixel(x: Int, y: Int, color: Color);
```

I can fix it myself by changing line 3 to:

```
sealed class Pixel(x: Int, y: Int, color: javafx.scene.paint.Color);
```

But I think this is kinda ugly, so is't there a better way to use an imported class?

---

Also, i get this warning

```
imported `Color' is permanently hidden by definition of object Color in package drawingengine
import javafx.scene.paint.Color
```

and IntelliJ greys out the importing line as if it is not used.

I can see that [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971399/permanently-hidden-warning-in-scala-application) have had the same problem, but I don't see how the shown example applies to what i am doing.
So what can I do about this warning?

Comment: I think your IDE is not able to import javafx.scene.paint.Color. can you try it on a notepad

Comment: Isn't warning explains it all? You have `drawingengine.Color` in your project. Rename it (or remove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you have defined your own `Color` class, inside the same package `drawingengine`, and that it is colliding with the JavaFX one.
This

```
javafx.scene.paint.Color
```

fixes it because you explicitly use a qualified name.
If you want to maintain both of them, you might alias the JavaFX one

```
import javafx.scene.paint.{Color => FxColor}
```

And use it like

```
sealed class Pixel(x: Int, y: Int, color: FxColor);
```